# Compute the volume of a polytope using the coordinates of its vertices

Tags: combinatorics, volume, polyhedra, simplex

Probabily is an easy question but I have no references for it.

Let we consider a bounded, convex polytope $P$ in the space $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Assuming we know the coordinates of its vertices $v_1 , \dots , v_k$, is there an easy way to compute the volume of $P$?

In the case one of these vertices is the origin, is the calculation any simpler?

What about if the vertices are exactly $n+1$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a triangulation and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html

Comment: If there are exactly $n+1$ points, they are the vertices of a simplex. Subtract one point from all of the points, effectively moving it to the origin. Take the determinant of the remaining $n$ points, and divide by $n!$ to get the volume.